# Evaluating a postfix Expression in C

Tags: c, postfix-notation

I'm trying to write a program that evaluates a postfix arithmetic expression. The program sends a character string to my function `evaluatePostfix`, which proceeds to identify operands and operators and come up with an integer solution. I am manipulating stacks in this program by pushing the scanned character as it is identified and of course doing the appropriate pop functions when needing to evaluate. Right now though, I'm having a problem with the program hanging in what appears to be an infinite loop. I guess I'm not really sure how to tell the function to proceed to the next character in the string after it has evaluated the first character. Another thing to note is that the user puts a space in-between each operand and operator. Here is my function:

```
int evaluatePostfix(char *postfixStr)
{
    stack * s;
    int x, y;

    stackInit(&s);

    do {
        if(isOperand(postfixStr) == 1) {
            stackPush(&s, postfixStr);
        }

        if(isOperator(postfixStr) == 1) {
            y = atoi(stackPop(s));
            x = atoi(stackPop(s));
            char *str = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
            sprintf(str, "%d", applyOperator(x, y, postfixStr));
            stackPush(&s, str);
        }

    } while (postfixStr != NULL);
    return stackPop(s);
}
```

I know the functions that manipulate the stack are correct as they were provided by my instructor. Could someone perhaps give me a clue as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `while` condition to `while (++postfixStr != NULL)` to increment the pointer to the next character in `postfixStr`.

This increment is done using the prefix notation (`++var` vs `var++`) so that the next character is compared to `NULL`. I'm not familiar with the behavior of the stack functions you're using, but I would recommend changing the `do { ... } while (++postfixStr != NULL);` loop to a `while (postfixStr != NULL) { ... }` loop, and increment `postfixStr` at the end of that while loop's block.

The safest thing to do is add a string length parameter to your function:

```
int evaluatePostfix(char *postfixStr, int strLength)
```

You would then use a loop that explicitly steps from the beginning of the string at index `0` to index `strLength - 1`, which would safely handle empty and non-NULL-terminated strings.

Comment: I did as you suggested and got rid of the do - while loop in place for  a regular while loop and increment postfixStr at the end of the loop. After doing that however, the application crashes, and I can't quite figure out why. I modified the code to destroy the stack at the end of the function as I thought perhaps unfree memory was causing a problem... but no luck. Any thoughts perhaps?

Comment: What error message do you receive when it crashes? Have you run the code through a debugger or added debug print statements to find where the crash is occurring?

Comment: It seems to be a Windows error that occurs and it doesn't give me any explicit error message when it happens; it's only after a enter my postfix expression and hit the return key. I don't mean to sound like a complete dolt when I say this, but I can't seem to figure out how to debug in Code Blocks (which is the IDE that I'm using). I've only ever known how to debug in BlueJ, Eclipse and Netbeans, but getting those configured to compile C was becoming a pain so I opted for Code Blocks. I'll see if I can't try to figure that out :/

Comment: Ah - I figured it out ^_^ (How to debug that is)... It seems that my stack is empty... but it should be reading the postfix expression left to right, so it should be seeing the operand first. I wonder what I could be forgetting to do >.>